# egrep working differently on SunOS and RHEL

Tags: regex, grep, rhel, sunos

I've an `egrep` statement(as a part of a script) purpose of which is to check for any characters other than ASCII characters `0-9, a-z, A-Z, space, enter, newline`. Also if text is enclosed in `[]`, it can contain `0-9, a-z, A-Z, _, =` which works perfectly as I expect on a RHEL box:

```
uname -a
Linux labeir1 2.6.18-371.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 5 21:21:44 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
cat /etc/redhat\-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga)
```

The `egrep` statement:

```
egrep -v "^[ ]*([a-zA-Z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]*|\[{1}[_a-zA-Z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]*(=[a-zA-Z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]*)?\]{1})[ ]*$" file1
```

File1:

```
[FEATURE_ID=2]
[FEATURE_REV=1]
[NO_OF_BYTES=18]
001203658080400160b9d0ae45000080
[CRC]
c068
```

Output:

```
Nothing, as the patterns of file1 matches
```

But when I use this on a SunOS system, it fails to behave the same way:

```
uname -a
SunOS prodOTA1 5.9 Generic_118558-38 sun4us sparc FJSV,GPUZC-M
```

Output on SUNOS:

```
[FEATURE_ID=2]
[FEATURE_REV=1]
[NO_OF_BYTES=18]
[CRC]
```

Can you please help to use the exact equivalent of `egrep -v "^[ ]*([a-zA-Z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]*|\[{1}[_a-zA-Z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]*(=[a-zA-Z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]*)?\]{1})[ ]*$"` in SunOS, so that I get the exact output as in RHEL box.

Comment: I don't know but you can start to remove these useless `{1}`.

Comment: the regex you're using, and the requirements you list, do not match, not even in intent.

Comment: about the group: Indeed I didn't see it (but refresh the page, this part of my comment no longer exists). About `{1}`: It is totally useless, it doesn't ensure anything, remove it, never write it again.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Its grouped under `()` . Also I'm using the `{1}` because I want to make sure patterns like `[[[text=text]`, `text=text]` should not match. Only pattern like `[text_text=text]`, `[text=text]`, `[text]` or `text` should match. where by `text` I mean `0-9,a-z,A-Z,space,newline,tab,enter`

Comment: @sweaver2112 Here is what I want to achieve : Only pattern like `[text_text=text]`, `[text=text]`, `[text]` or `text` should match. where by `text` I mean `0-9,a-z,A-Z,space,newline,tab,enter`. Anything other than this will not match i.e `egrep -v` should show it. How can I achieve this in SunOS

Comment: No it shouldn't because the `-v` parameter inverts the result.

Comment: I want to make sure patterns like `[[[text_text=text]`, `text_text=text]` , `[[[text=text]` `text=text] `[text=text` should not match as well

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com may be a better place for this question.

Comment: Try to unescape the closing square bracket, remove the `{1}`s, remove `\n\v\f\r` from the character classes.